# Error Codes: This method must return a result of type String && dead code in a for loop within the toString method

Tags: java, computer-science

This is the toString method.    groceries[] is Type Geoceries, length of 6, values have been assigned eariler. There are two mistakes. One is on return a result of type String, which I did, second mistake is n++ is dead code. What should I do if I want to return information of groceries[1], groceries[2],...

```
public String toString()//Error:This method must return a result of type String
{
    
    if(groceries==null)
    {   
        return "No Groceries";
    }
    else
    {
        for(int n=0; n<groceries.length; n++)//n++ is dead code
        {   String str=groceries[n].toString();//this toString is from Groceries Class
            return str;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: dead code - why have a loop when you force it only to iterate once?  b) return value - what do you think can be returned if the Array is empty?

Comment: I use loop because once toString is called, I want to display all info stored in each array element. Is there any other way to make this? If the array is empty, it should return NULL?

Comment: I have made an answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you change your code to

```
public String toString()
{
    
    if(groceries==null)
    {   
        return "No Groceries";
    }

    return Arrays.toString (groceries);
```

Or if you really want to loop, then you will ned to appended each item

```
StringBuilder rv = new StringBuilder ();
else
{
    for(int n=0; n<groceries.length; n++)
    {   
        String str=groceries[n].toString();
        rv.append (str);
        rv.append (",");
    }
}
return rv.toString ();
```

There are other ways as well.